# How to change view of a widget in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Let's say,I have a widget that shows the content of my website .

[image]

There is a refresh icon png in the left bottom corner of my widget.

[image]

Now,I would like the refresh icon rotate itself until I get content from my server.

How can I do ?

Comment: You have to override the ondraw() method of the view to make your own custom view Follow this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: It is not possible to access directly to the view in the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsynkTask, start Rotation animation in onPreExecute() and stop animation in onPostExecute() method

Comment: I know, but in the widget I can not access to the imageview. I should use remoteViews.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the view directly because the view within a widget is placed outside your process (outside your address and memory space).
The widget view is placed within some system process and system makes all the calls to the `android.view.View` or `android.view.ViewGroup` directly.
Android allows external processes access these 'embedded' views by using [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) class.

The RemoteViews class represents a set of actions that system should do in order to modify the internal view. For example [RemoteViews.setViewVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewVisibility(int,%20int)) is an equivalent of [View.setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)).

Now once you have the above in mind you see that there's no way of overriding view classes in the view hierarchy (because there is no simple enough way of transferring that class override down to a system process and make system use that implementation instead of the "stock" one).

As a solution to your problem you have two views in the view hierarchy.
The one would be the rotating button and the other the button which reacts to touches.
When user touches the button view you then hide it and show the rotating view. Upon server's response you would hide first view and show the button view back again.